# I need to display the running time which will start with 0

Tags: c#, timer

I need to display the time which will start with `0` and (which will keep running in seconds)
I need to display in a game so it will show elapsed time when playing.
as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

someone told me to do this way,

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();
```

and display it with

```
Console.WriteLine(st.Elapsed);
```

but its not working (seconds are not running)!
it showing as:

[image]

Comment: when are you trying to display it with relation to .Start() and the output to console? There is the possibility there are microseconds or less between execution. We don't know what the context of the Console.WriteLine() is- if it is really right after it, chances are it is going through too fast to have any seconds display. Try following the example from MSDN- add a Thread.Sleep(10000); for a test validation that some time has definitely elapsed before the console gets called.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Did you put the code in a loop? As it stands there's nowhere near enough information here for anyone to offer meaningful help.

Comment: `var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); new System.Threading.Timer((e)=>Console.Write(sw.Elapsed.Seconds + "\r"), null, 0, 1000);`

Comment: this is how i am trying,
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Chances:" + " " + Chances + "\t" + "\t" + " Marks:" + " " + Marks+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"Time Elapsed:" + st.Elapsed.Seconds);

Comment: @ L.B
sir, your code is working but not as i want.
it just start timer at the end of console.
i want it as Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time:" + i wantHere);

Comment: @AnuragKushwaha Don't be lazy and change it the way you want.

Comment: @ L.B i am not being lazy, i just don't know what to do with your code.
i mean can you tell me how to show time in my code, i mean on the place of st.Elapsed.Seconds

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you just need to update your display every 1 second so why not just use a `Timer` which will run every 1 second and increment whatever you display on the screen. (Read about Timer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

You can find an example here: 
[How to set timer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023113/how-to-set-timer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Given this is a console game: Have the Elapsed time from the StopWatch stored in a TimeSpan and then just use the Thread.Sleep(); property from System.Threading(); to simulate 1 second.

```
        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = st.Elapsed;
            string time = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            Console.Write("\r{0}     ", time);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

PS: This is my first answer in this website and I hope I was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a game, there must be the `animation (game) loop` somewhere. You should put

```
Console.WriteLine(st.Elapsed);
```

there. This way it is going to refresh correctly.